# programmatically create headers and evaluate following code chunks in markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

My question is similar to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43752095/programmatically-insert-header-and-plot-in-same-code-chunk-with-r-markdown-using) but instead of creating a plot, I want to evaluate code chunk. I wanted to know if it's possible to programmatically generate headers **and** evaluate code chunks following their respective headers?  My attempt at this is below.

I have a `list` of data frames that I want to create a header and evaluate code chunk for each `list` element. The example below is just to calculate the number of rows of each data frame using `nrow()`.

````
```{r data}
data("iris","airquality","mtcars")
my_list <- list(iris,airquality,mtcars)
names(my_list) <- c("iris","airquality","mtcars")
```
````

````
```{r headers, results = 'asis'}
for (i in seq_along(my_list)) {
  cat('#', names(my_list)[i], '\n')
  cat('```{r}', '\n')

  cat('nrow(mylist[[i]])') #evaluate any other code here

  cat('\n')
  cat('```')
  cat('\n')
}
```
````

Any insight would be much appreciated!

Comment: That seems reasonable on first glance, have you `knit` to markdown and seen what the results look like? You might see just from doing that.

Comment: @r2evans i have tried to `knit` the markdown and the headers are fine but the code chunk just says `nrow(mylist[[i]])` and it is not being evaluated

Answer (score 3):

This behavior is because R cannot find your `mylist` object within the new environment that is getting created by all the `cat` calls. Also since `mylist[[i]]` is an expression we would have to parse and evaluate it to get the final result.

For example -

````
```{r headers, results = 'asis'}
for (i in seq_along(my_list)) {
  cat('#', names(my_list)[i], '\n')
  cat('```{r}', '\n')
  cat(eval(parse(text = 'i')))

  cat('\n')
  cat('```')
  cat('\n')
}
```
````

The above code will give a result as follows (this is the result we need)-

````
# iris 
```{r} 
1
```
# airquality 
```{r} 
2
```
# mtcars 
```{r} 
3
```
````

But to do that with `mylist` we would need to somehow make sure that mylist object is within the new environment before it can be evaluated. Also please note that people discourage the use of `parse()` since it can lead to behaviors such as this. More here - [Assigning and removing objects in a loop: eval(parse(paste(](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710978/assigning-and-removing-objects-in-a-loop-evalparsepaste)

This answer will work for your example but please do consider what I have mentioned and the discussion in the SO question -

````
```{r data}
data("iris","airquality","mtcars")
my_list <- list(iris,airquality,mtcars)
names(my_list) <- c("iris","airquality","mtcars")
```

```{r headers, results = 'asis'}
for (i in seq_along(my_list)) {
  cat('#', names(my_list)[i], '\n')
  cat('```{r}', '\n')

  # somehow get the data or any other objects in here
  # this works for trivial examples please be carefule before using it on actual code chunks
  cat(eval(parse(text = paste(nrow(my_list[[i]])))))


  cat('\n')
  cat('```')
  cat('\n')
}
```

# iris 
```{r} 
150
```
# airquality 
```{r} 
153
```
# mtcars 
```{r} 
32
```
````

Comment: Thanks for the explanation - I should go back and give the _Advanced R Environments_ chapter a read. As you suggested, this method would not great due to using `parse`. I've found an alternative method to generate a similar output in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21729415/generate-dynamic-r-markdown-blocks).

Comment: Would you mind posting a small sample of what you end up doing as the answer to this question? I think everyone will be interested in these kind of issues

Comment: I’ll create a sample once I get a chance

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way that I tackle a problem similar to this. I was given the hint here on SO but cannot find the answer ...

Two documents: one parent, one child. Think of the child document as a subroutine that can be called any number of times, and its output is saved (and concatenated to the `character` vector `out`). When I'm done in that loop, I use an inline `` `r code` `` block.

The main document, the "parent" I guess:

````
---
output: md_document
---

```{r data}
data("iris","airquality","mtcars")
my_list <- list(iris,airquality,mtcars)
names(my_list) <- c("iris","airquality","mtcars")
```

```{r headers, echo = FALSE, include = FALSE, results = 'asis'}
out <- NULL
for (i in seq_along(my_list)) {
  out <- c(out, knitr::knit_child("somedoc-child.Rmd"))
}
```

`r paste(out, collapse="\n")`
````

The child document, same directory, called as `somedoc-child.Rmd` above, called by the parent doc. It sees the environment exactly as the parent leaves it, so `my_list` and `i` are seen perfectly.

````
# `r names(my_list[i])`

```{r, results="asis"}
nrow(my_list[[i]])
```
````

When I knit to markdown, I get:

```
    data("iris","airquality","mtcars")
    my_list <- list(iris,airquality,mtcars)
    names(my_list) <- c("iris","airquality","mtcars")

iris
====

    nrow(my_list[[i]])

\[1\] 150

airquality
==========

    nrow(my_list[[i]])

\[1\] 153

mtcars
======

    nrow(my_list[[i]])

\[1\] 32
```

Comment: I like the idea of using `child` documents and that's definitely something I need to read into. I've found an alternative method recently to create a similar output in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21729415/generate-dynamic-r-markdown-blocks) using the `knit_expand()` function. Thanks for the help

Comment: That's another approach, and I hadn't seen that yet. It seems that the differences are minor, so the effect should be the same (especially since they both capture the output into `out` and dump them after the chunk).